# Is there an error in the score of Luo Ni's "G Minor Bach"?

Tags: piano, sheet-music

In this score of "G Minor Bach" by Luo Ni (which is a kind of remix of Bach)

in the note that I circle in red, the sound is very strange.

Is it correct? Do you also hear a strange sound when you play this note on the piano?

[image: "G Minor Bach" by Luo Ni, mm. 22–25]

The recording can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nvrtau72PA0)

(NOTE: This video must be viewed in YouTube; it cannot be viewed in SE, because the video owner has disabled that option. Also, the video version contains a few additional measures added just before the segment I'm asking about. **The part in question occurs at 1:36**.)

There is also this part which is very strange :
[image]

it is almost impossible to play the left hand since we already have the thumb
on the F : how could we play the G just after with the thumb at high speed : this is not natural at all : is the note correct ?

Comment: What is the piece?

Comment: This is "G minor" by Luo Ni: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nvrtau72PA0

Comment: remark : in the link, she adds a bit more measure before to do this measure, so it is not 100 % synchronized with the score above.

Comment: Where did the notation come from? Are you sure it's an accurate transcription?

Comment: For example we see it on measure 24 of this link https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DI-X0VzSC5tE&ved=2ahUKEwjzkY-AqK_wAhUQlxQKHYNdDycQwqsBegQICxAB&usg=AOvVaw1J2R-bYPAB1P2ilM5hwGXC

Comment: I should find the exact place where I downloaded it.

Comment: The place of the score is https://sheet.host/sheet/Gjj5UL

Comment: The recent edit is a separate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the recording provided, **the score is incorrect.**

In the left hand, the notes accompanying the right-hand's `Gb` should be `C-Gb` not `C-F`. (Actually, both right-hand and left-hand should be `F#`; see below.)

The chord comprising beat 2 (`Ab C Gb Eb`) is an augmented sixth chord resolving to the `G` chord on beat three. The "correct" spelling would be `Ab C Eb F#`.

Comment: Actually in youtube she replays a part so the measure 24 is done later to the number in the score that I put

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian I matched the score to the recording, compensating for the added measures in the recording. I also added a time-stamped link to your OP, which corresponds exactly to the pictured score.

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian FYI: I've updated your original question to clarify how the video corresponds to the score.

Comment: Here at 1:10, he really plays the score that I said, but we don't hear a strange sound : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DRcVKXctvXo

Comment: In this recording, the left-hand plays very softly, so the clash between the right and left hands is not so apparent.

Answer (score 2):

There is an `F` natural in the bass with a `G` flat in the treble, a minor ninth.

*If* you disregard the `F` natural and change the `G` flat to enharmonic `F` sharp, then you would have ascending the chord `Ab C F# Eb` arpeggiated of beat two. That could be heard as a dominant ninth in `4/3` inversion. It does move to a `G` chord next, so that makes sense.

The "odd" sounding part is the actual `F` natural in the bass clef. Depending on how you spell that `Gb/F#` in the treble, you have a clashing *cross relationship* with those pitches.

Comment: A couple of typos? 1) A C F# Eb should be Ab ...? And 2) "It doesn't move to a G chord"; "It does move to a G chord"?

Comment: Are you saying that the measure score is correct or that it is wrong ?

Comment: @Aaron, thanks! Some days, ugh! The brain/typing connection doesn't work.

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian, yes, I think the score is wrong. But right or wrong the thing that sounds strange is the cross relationship. Sometimes a cross relationship is intentional, but I don't think so in this case.

Comment: @Michael Curtis : ok, but what is the "solution" : how this mistake it be corrected ? Indeed, when we hear people that play it we don't hear the strange sound : this means that there are not playing this for this measure...

Comment: That's a totally different question, and BTW off topic. But a quick Google turns up what appear to be various copies of the same transcription. I didn't find a page for Luo Ni. Hoped she may have posted her own score, but it appears not. Honestly, my first thought was "why not just play Back, BWV 847?"

Comment: why not play Bach, BWV 847 ? Because this new version is much more pretty than the original of Bach...

Comment: But you don't have a score to play from. How much time do you want to dump into this endeavor? I would move on to other music, whatever you like, but stuff with professionally produced scores.

Answer (score 1):

First, a minor ninth can be fun... but can also be a typo. I have no idea.

About the fingering: I myself would try playing the Eb-Bb-Eb to have thumb on the top Eb, and cross over to get my second finger on the F, freeing up my thumb for the G...